# Do file terminal command contains /* - How can I prevent this from commenting out further work?

Tags: for-loop, terminal, stata

So, I know that `mv` tends to work better for moving files around, so while in Stata I wanted to move all the files which contained a certain year in the name to their own directories. However, when I include `/*` in the `!` terminal command, it comments out the rest of my work in the do file. Is there any way to work around this?

Here is the section in question:

```
forvalues i = 2010/2013 {
    !mkdir ~/Documents/Thesis/Data/EIA_AMI/Test/`i'
    !mv ~/Documents/Thesis/Data/EIA_AMI/Test/*`i'* ~/Documents/Thesis/Data/EIA_AMI/Test/`i'/
}
```

Comment: What if you put quotes around the paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach is to use `filelist` (from SSC) to create a dataset of files to manage and do all the file maintenance in Stata. The following example assumes that in Stata's current directory there a directory called "from" that contains a bunch of files with a year in the name.

```
. filelist, dir(from) norecur
Number of files found = 6

. list

     +--------------------------------------+
     | dirname   filename             fsize |
     |--------------------------------------|
  1. | from      test2010test 3.txt   8,540 |
  2. | from      test2010test.txt        17 |
  3. | from      test2010test2.txt        9 |
  4. | from      test2011test 3.txt       5 |
  5. | from      test2011test.txt         3 |
     |--------------------------------------|
  6. | from      test2011test2.txt        3 |
     +--------------------------------------+
```

The code below will create a new directory called "years" in the current directory and subdirectories named after the years. By using only relative directories and only Stata commands, you make your code more portable. Of course, the following could be modified to use shell commands to process each file.

```
* filelist if from SSC
filelist, dir(from) norecur

* extract the year from the file name
gen year = regexs(1) if regexm(filename,"([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])")
assert !mi(year)

* automatically discover years
levelsof year, clean
local years `r(levels)'

* create destination directories if they don't alread exist
cap mkdir "years"
foreach y of local years {
    cap mkdir "years/`y'"
}

* use Stata commands to copy the files one by one.
local obs = _N
forvalues i = 1/`obs' {
    local fname = filename[`i']
    local dname = dirname[`i']
    local from = "`dname'/`fname'"
    local year = year[`i']

    local to = "years/`year'/`fname'"
    copy "`from'" "`to'", replace
    rm "`from'"
}
```

After running the above example, I get

```
. filelist , dir(years)
Number of files found = 6

. list

     +-----------------------------------------+
     | dirname      filename             fsize |
     |-----------------------------------------|
  1. | years/2010   test2010test 3.txt   8,540 |
  2. | years/2010   test2010test.txt        17 |
  3. | years/2010   test2010test2.txt        9 |
  4. | years/2011   test2011test 3.txt       5 |
  5. | years/2011   test2011test.txt         3 |
     |-----------------------------------------|
  6. | years/2011   test2011test2.txt        3 |
     +-----------------------------------------+
```

Comment: How would I change this to index the subdirectories as well?  My issue is that some of the zips that I'm extracting extract to directories with years in them. Others extract direct to my working directory. Either I need them to create directories in the working directory and move the files there, or into a directory called "years" and then move all the files in year named subdirectories into this new subdirectory

Comment: Just remove the `norecur` option on the first `filelist` and you'll get a full listing of all the files. You can then decide what to do for each based on the filename and/or directory path.

Comment: Thanks Robert! This is definitely the most elegant solution running fully in STATA. The last thing I'm trying to figure out is how to sort the few files that don't have years on them into an unsorted file. I'll tinker with else commands with year definition and see if I can come up with something.

Answer (score 1):

Try ASCII codes with the `char()` function if surrounding with quotes doesn't work.

A working example on my machine is:

```
clear all 
set more off

forvalues i = 2010/2010 {
    !mkdir ~/Desktop/test/`i'
    !mv /home/roberto/Desktop/test/`=char(42)'`i'`=char(42)'.txt /home/roberto/Desktop/test/`i'/
}
```

with

[image]

The result is:

[image]

An example run:

```
. local i = 2010

. // initial state
. !ls ~/Desktop/test

test2010test.txt

. // move
. !mkdir ~/Desktop/test/`i'


. !mv ~/Desktop/test/`=char(42)'`i'`=char(42)'.txt ~/Desktop/test/`i'/


. // final state
. !ls ~/Desktop/test

2010

. !ls ~/Desktop/test/2010

test2010test.txt
```

Comment: Well, that gets the asterisks in place, but they no longer act as wildcards.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably find some luck storing the file path in a local *in quotes* and then evaluating that local in the `mv` call:

```
. do move.do

. ls

move.do
testDir/
testFile1.txt
testFile2.md

. local cmd "./*.txt testDir/"

. !mv `cmd'

. ls

move.do
testDir/
testFile2.md

. ls testDir/

testFile1.txt
```

What's interesting is that the `/*` gets interpreted as a comment if you don't go through a local. I'm sure people with better understanding of Stata can explain why, but I can't.

```
. !mv "./*.md testDir/"

mv: missing destination file operand after `./*.md testDir/'
Try `mv --help' for more information.

. ls

move.do
testDir/
testFile2.md

. ls testDir/

testFile1.txt

end of do-file
```

Comment: Is this an interactive run? I can see it working interactively, but not in a do-file.

Comment: Good point. Didn't test it in a do-file. Putting quotes around the local contents does the trick. I'll edit my answer.